# Remove any paragraph tags that have a child of img, but do not remove the img

Tags: jquery, dom, expressionengine

I'm working with a CMS (ExpressionEngine) that wraps paragraph tags around images. I'm using responsive images (max-width:100%) and since I'm also defining widths on my paragraphs, its causing problems. I'd like to use jQuery to remove the paragraph tags that are wrapped around the images. I'd also like to be able to have the width and height properties removed from the images as well, as these aren't needed in combination with max-width:100%.

Here's an example of the HTML before modification:

```
<div class="content">
<p>Hello! This is text content in a blog post.</p>
<p><img src="hello.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="Hello!" /></p>
<p>This is more text content in the blog pst.</p>
</div>
```

...and here's what I'd like the result to be:

```
<div class="content">
<p>Hello! This is text content in a blog post.</p>
<img src="hello.jpg" alt="Hello!" />
<p>This is more text content in the blog pst.</p>
</div>
```

I could just change ExpressionEngine's field format from "XHTML" to "none", but that would require the person posting content to write HTML which I'd prefer to avoid. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
$('p > img').removeAttr('height').removeAttr('width').unwrap();
```

This will work for an `<img>` wrapped in an `<a>`:

```
$('p > a > img').removeAttr('height').removeAttr('width').parent().unwrap();
```

Comment: That's great, much simpler than I expected. Thank you!

Comment: Here's something I missed - some of the images will have anchor tags around them. In that case, I'd still like to remove the paragraph tag around the image and its anchor, but keep the image and its anchor tag. Can that be done in a similar fashion?

Comment: @EricCarl Try $('p').find('img').unwrap().removeAttr('height').removeAttr('width');

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the enclosing node using [`.unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap), and the attributes using [`removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr)...

```
$('.content > p > img').unwrap()
                       .removeAttr('width height')
```

Comment: @KeithFrey: No I don't. [An Open Letter to JavaScript Leaders Regarding Semicolons](http://blog.izs.me/post/2353458699/an-open-letter-to-javascript-leaders-regarding)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [jQuery.unwrap](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) and reset the height/width while you're at it:

```
$('p > img').each(function() {
  $(this).unwrap();
  this.height = '';
  this.width = '';
});
```

Comment: ooh fancy, I didn't know about the unwrap function

Answer (score 1):

Use a selector to find p tags with images in them, then pull that node out and put it back:

```
var $img = $('p').find('img');
$img.parent().replaceWith($img);
$img.css('height','');
$img.css('width','');
```

This is untested, so I'm not totally sure the logic is right, but these are the basic functions/flow you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this:

```
$('p + img').replaceWith(function() {
  return $(this).contents().removeAttr('width height');
});
```

stole the last bit from above